# Correct usage in relative clause

Tags: meaning, relative-clauses

> I need to find the man whose son you said (((he))) tried to find a job .

Should I use “he” after “you said” ? Or it can be understood that “ the one you talked about is son of the man ?

Comment: It reads well without the "he" and your second sentence could be better as "The one you talked about is **the** son of **that** man."

Comment: The relative clause is understood as "You said that the man's son tried to find a job", where the subject of the relative clause is ""whose son"; thus no further subject ("he") is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is correct without 'he'. It is incorrect with 'he'.

In this case, 'son' is the subject of the clause so if you add another subject, 'he', it is redundant.  We know the son is the son of the man because of the possessive, 'whose'.

> His son tried to find a job.
>   He is the man whose son tried to find a job.
>   You said his son tried to find a job.
>   He is the man whose son you said tried to find a job.

Answer (score 0):

With the *he*, your sentence accepts a different interpretation:

> I need to find the man (let's call him Smith) whose son you said he (Jones) tried to find a job [for].

Answer (score 0):

There are two different meanings, depending on whether you include "he".

When you include **he**, the man tried to find a job for his son:

> I need to find the man whose son you said he tried to find a job.

When you don't include **he**, it's the son who tried to find a job:

> I need to find the man whose son you said tried to find a job.

Both examples are very awkward. Here are suggestions for improvement:

> I need to find the man who tried to find a job for his son.
>
> I need to find the man with the son who tried to find a job.